# C++ Single character not being sent over socket

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

I want to send a single character over a socket. On the receiving end, it always ends up as a null character. Any suggestions?

Sending part

```
char message[7];
in_addr addr;
inet_aton(splitter_socket_.local_endpoint().address().to_string().c_str(), &addr);
(*(in_addr *)&message) = addr;
(*(uint16_t *)(message + 4)) = htons(splitter_socket_.local_endpoint().port());
(*(char *)(message+6))=htons('M');
splitter_socket_.send(boost::asio::buffer(message));
```

Receiving part

```
boost::array<char, 7> buf;
char *raw_data = buf.data();
boost::asio::ip::address ip_addr;
int port;

read((*serve_socket), boost::asio::buffer(buf));
in_addr ip_raw = *(in_addr *)(raw_data);
ip_addr = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(inet_ntoa(ip_raw));
port = ntohs(*(short *)(raw_data + 4));
char sig = ntohs(*(char *)(raw_data+6));
```

This always gets executed. Meaning, sig is always a null character
But I had sent 'M'. That's missing.

```
if(sig==0){
  number_of_monitors_++;
  TRACE("The number of monitors increased to "<<number_of_monitors_);
}
```

The rest of the data I'm sending is being received properly

Comment: I don't know ASIO but I know it is asynchronous. Are you sure that ASIO is not using the buffer after you've returned from the function which called `send`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing `htons` on the 'M'.

That's going to sign extend the 'M' to a short, then (since you're apparently on a little-endian machine) byte-swap it, so what you're sending is the upper byte of the sign-extended version, which will be a `0`, since 'M' is guaranteed to be positive.

A `char` isn't a `short`, so it shouldn't be treated as one. Just transmit the `char` as-is.

Comment: Arent characters 1 byte long?

Comment: @Rakshith: Yes, but a short is 2 bytes long. `htons` takes a short as its parameter and returns a short, so your char gets promoted to `short` as you call `htons`.